# How to make rspec expect-receive to only care about some method call

Tags: rspec

I have a Rails model that has two after_save callbacks, each one calls a method on `QueuePublisher` class with different arguments.

I want to test the callbacks separately, so that one test tests that my QueuePublisher gets a certain input, and another test tests the second input. If I write the test like this:

```
expect(QueuePublisher).to receive(:publish_messages).with("argument1").once
```

The test fails when the second after_save callback is calling QueuePublisher with different argument. How can I make the test to ignore the rest of the method calls and just be happy about that "argument1" was received once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `allow` both calls `.with("their specific arguments")` in both tests. This sets up a spy for each one, allowing them to happen and not interfere with the other spy.

```rb
allow(QueuePublisher).to receive(:publish_messages).with("argument1")
allow(QueuePublisher).to receive(:publish_messages).with("argument2")

model.save

expect(QueuePublisher).to have_received(:publish_messages).with("argument1").once
```

Also, note that I'm not using the same expectation syntax. I've separated the spy from the expectation by using `allow` and `expect().to have_received`.

Comment: Thanks. This is more or less what I needed to do. I added a `expect(QueuePublisher).to receive(:publish_messages)` to catch all other calls to the method. Just feels dumb that I need to add it. I mean, the publish_messages method was called with "argument1", so the test should pass. It was called with other arguments too, but that should not matter.

Comment: The expectation that it will receive "argument1" specifically excludes all other parameters. Any other parameter is considered a violation of that expectation unless you allow them. That's one of the reasons I prefer the other syntax. It's more explicit about what it's doing.

Comment: If only "argument1" would be expected, then it should be possible to define it with `expect(QueuePublisher).to receive(:publish_messages).with("argument1").only` or something similar.

Comment: That would say the same thing to me.

Comment: Dude. RSpec is open source. Commit the code you want to see in the world.